# Is the mean of sampled squared errors the best estimate of the actual mean squared error?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, estimation

For an estimator characterized by Gaussian white noise, is the mean of sampled squared errors the best estimate of the estimator's actual mean squared error. Or, should the mean of sampled squared errors be adjusted? If so, how?

Comment: are you talking about [biased vs unbiased sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) aka Bessel's correction?

Comment: Yes, that appears to give me the answer. Thank you.